# How to get file name of current template inside Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Say I use `return render_template('index.html', users=users)`. Is it possible to get the filename inside a template without explicit sending of it inside the view?

Comment: just wondering: what are you trying to do? (interested in the answer)

Comment: I second @JeffTratner. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to add a class to body depending on a filename. For example, if it's "user-details.html" template, I want to add a respective class <body class="user-details"> to manage it through javascript properly.

Comment: Can be used in warnings to tell the file I need to fix.

Answer (score 28):

Although undocumented, `{{ self._TemplateReference__context.name }}` will give the template name.   And there are a number of interresting attributes that you can use after `self._TemplateReference__context`.

You could, for example, add this to your topmost base template:

```
        <meta name="template" content="{{ self._TemplateReference__context.name }}">
```

So that looking at a page source will help you quickly find the relevant template file.   If you don't want to expose this kind of information, make it conditional to testing environment.

Comment: If the current template is inherited, then (Jinja2.10) this will give you the root template's name, not the current template.

Answer (score 8):

If all you need is the basename, you can use `{{ self }}` which will return a repr string containing the basename of the template, e.g., `<TemplateReference 'view.html'>`. You could parse this with a filter, e.g., `{{ self | quoted }}`

```
@app.template_filter('quoted')
def quoted(s):
    l = re.findall('\'([^\']*)\'', str(s))
    if l:
        return l[0]
    return None
```

If you need the full path, e.g., '/full/path/to/view.html' you may want to subclass Template.

Comment: It doesn't work. When I try your solution, this error is raised: TemplateAssertionError: no filter named 'quoted'

Comment: @renatov: Where do you have @app.template_filter('quoted')? Is the filter properly registered with your Flask app?