# Jinja - Is there any built-in variable to get current HTML page name?

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2

i'm very new to Jinja and Flask

I want to set different background color in the navigation bar to indicate the current page.

Is there any built-in Jinja variable or method that returns current HTML pages? If possible, I want the code that doesn't need to communicate with the Python file.

So if i'm currently in `index.html`, it will return "index" or "index.html"

Here's my navigation code in my template:

```
<ul>
   {% for item in navigation %}
       <a href="{{url_for(item.route)}}">
       <li>
           {{item.text}}
       </li>
       </a>
   {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to add `if` statement so the current page will get `<li>` that has `class`

```
{% if ??? %}
   <li class="current">
   ...
   </li>
{% else %}
   ...
{% endif %}
```

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11157631/388916

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a trick in jinja2 document for your problem: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/

If your list is simple enough, just using request object, something like that:

```
<li {% if request.endpoint == item.endpoint %} class='active' {% endif %}>
    <a href="{{url_for(endpoint)}}">{{item.text}}</a>
</li>
```

Normally, I write this snippet to a macro with an explicit argument to set `active`:

```
{% macro render_sitem(endpoint, display, cls='', icon-cls='', active='') %}
<li {% if request.endpoint == endpoint or active == endpoint %} class='active' {% endif %}>
    <a class='{{cls}}' href="{{url_for(endpoint)}}"><i class="{{icon-cls}}"></i> {{display}}</a>
</li>
{% endmacro %}
```

The list will be something like:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-list">
     {{render_sitem('page.index',  _('Pages'), icon-cls='icon-sitemap', active=active_page)}}
     {{render_sitem('post.index', _('Posts'), icon-cls='icon-file', active=active_page)}}
     {{render_sitem('user.index', _('Users'), icon-cls='icon-group', active=active_page)}}
 </ul>
```

So if you have a child page which extends or includes your list, you can set active item like:

```
{% set active_page = 'page.index' %}
```

in the top of your child page.

Answer (score 5):

In pyramid 1.5 there are no method like request.endpoint in Flask.

We use custom filter get_endpoint

> request.path|get_endpoint

jinja2_custom_filters.py:

```
from pyramid_jinja2 import Environment

def get_endpoint(str):
    """

    :param str:
    :return:
    """
    return str.split('/')[-1]


env = Environment()
env.filters['get_endpoint'] = get_endpoint
```

and in development.ini:

```
jinja2.filters =
    model_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:model_url_filter
    route_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:route_url_filter
    static_url = pyramid_jinja2.filters:static_url_filter
    get_endpoint = path to ... jinja2_custom_filters.get_endpoint
```

Maybe it will be useful to someone :)

Answer (score 1):

In Flask 2.0.1, the `request` object is available in the template. With this you can easily use it to check the page using the `request.path` attribute.

An example of a check would be like this:

```html
{% if request.path == "/" %}
  <h1>You are at the root</h1>
{% endif %}
```