# I want less output for printer and to fit on one page

Tags: browser, rendering

I have a google-app-engine app that produces a signup sheet for neighborhood tennis courts. My first test court has told me that on any given day they want to be able to print tomorrow's sheet as one page. [The answer here suggests using jinja for a similar goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665401/) where I assume I would have some output of the full browser app elided for the printed result. But are there other strategies in jinja or css or ... that will enable me to force the output onto a single page. [You can see a typical page which includes all the output here. I would want only the table and the date **printed**.](http://reservationschedule.appspot.com/reserve/Brians/2)

Comment: To be more specific about what Kevin said, you can use CSS media types to specify different stylesheets when displaying on the screen versus when displaying for printing.

Comment: It looks like I can use `display: none` to skip parts I don't want. And set font sizes, and line heights, also. That's great. I've got my fingers crossed that it will work for me.