# Advanced: How to use href in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, pyramid

I want to use `href` in the `jinja2` template to send the user to the the specific result based on `id` to learn more about that particular result. I created a `route` url : `('view_assessment_result', '/view_assessment_result/{id}')` that renders all the details about the specific result based on `id`.

**What I want to do:** 

When a user clicks on the `ID` number, they will be sent to the route `view_assessment_result/{some_id}` that will render the specifics of that page based on the `id` found in the iteration `for a in assessment...`. 
I tried looking into cases, but others seem to be using [Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665401/jinja-is-there-any-built-in-variable-to-get-current-html-page-name), which I am NOT using. The template code below is not accomplishing the task at hand.

See code below:

**route config:**

```
    #Route convention: resource 'name' 'url dispath'
    config.add_route('view_assessment_result', '/view_assessment_result/{id}')
```

**jinja template**

```
        <tr>
        {% for a in assessment_results %}
                <td><a href="{{ '/view_assessment_result' }}">{{ a.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ a.owner }}</td>
            <td>{{a.assessment }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

**view configuration that renders specific result sent by `href` above:**

```
@view_config(route_name='view_assessment_result', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/analyst_view.jinja2')
def view_assessment_result(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_result_id = int(request.matchdict['id'])
        assessment_result = api.retrieve_assessment_result(assessment_result_id)
        if not assessment_result:
            raise HTTPNotFound()
    #more code
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the id into your URL path. One way to add the id (from the Python variable `a.id` to your URL is to use the [`%` string formatting operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), like so:

```
<a href="{{ '/view_assessment_result/%s'%a.id }}">{{ a.id }}</a>
```

Also, if your `a.id` might include special characters (`/`, `&`, etc), you can escape them via the `urlencode` filter:

```
<a href="{{ '/view_assessment_result/%s'%a.id|urlencode }}">{{ a.id }}</a>
```

Comment: I'm getting '404 Not Found, The resource could not be found., /view_assessment_result` ... `{{a.id}}` simply prints a number, e.g. `2`

Comment: What URL generates the 404?

Comment: It worked when I changed your suggestion to this: `<a href="{{ '/view_assessment_result/%s'%a.id|urlencode }}">{{ a.id }}</a>` NOTE the change of `?` to `/`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Rob. Right now I am not running this on a static IP...thus the `0.0.0...` Thank you for your help! What does the `wild card` s and a represent here ?Mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: `%s` invokes [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), a fairly fundamental operation of Python strings.  If that is not familiar to you, you might want to go through the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/), which will explain that and many other aspects of the language. I'll add a reference to string formatting in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I am familiar with it in `Python` but thought it meant something else here. I am new to all this and am trying to learn/work ..  so I appreciate the guidance. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `request.route_path` to generate the URL.

```
<a href="{{ request.route_path('view_assessment_result', id=a.id) }}">{{ a.id }}</a>
```

Documentation here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.route_path